# How to define a MathJax specific macros (Rule and Space)

Tags: math-mode, mathjax

MathJax has a specific macros `\Rule #1 #2 #3` (command is used to create a rule with a specified width (#1), height(#2), and depth(#3)) and `\Space #1 #2 #3`(command is used to create a space with a specified width (#1), height(#2), and depth(#3)). How to define this macros in LaTeX? I know about `\rule`, but for example `\Rule{1em}{1ex}{2pt}` can not simple convert to `\rule` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say

```
\newcommand{\Rule}[3]{\vrule width #1 height #2 depth #3\relax}
\newcommand{\Space}[3]{\hspace*{#1}\vrule width 0pt height #2 depth #3\relax}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any possibility for Space command.

Comment: @DenisSletkov I'd say `\hspace*{#1}\vrule width 0pt height #2 depth #3\relax`